# Can't Get Rid of Auto Constraints Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I was recently having an issue with animating a `UITableView`.  It turned out that the issue was being caused by auto layout constraints.  I disabled auto layout for the `UITableView` by using the following code:

```
myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

This solved the issue but now every time I animate the `UITableView` I break the constraints placed on the frame and get the following warning.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x170a95db0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(538)-[UITableView:0x140330c00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170199640 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x170c9d010 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UITableView:0x140330c00(220)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x175e850a0 h=--& v=--& UITableView:0x140330c00.midY == + 458>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x175c97b10 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x170199640]   (Names: '|':UITransitionView:0x143942020 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x170a95db0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(538)-[UITableView:0x140330c00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170199640 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I need to use `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to make my animation work, but would like to get rid of this pesky warning.  Is there any way to eliminate this warning without removing `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`?

**Edit in response to comments:**

So the `UITableView` has a width of 320 and a height of 220.  It covers half of the screen and can be minimized or maximized.  The view is initialized with the `UITableView` in a minimized state with just the top section header showing at the bottom of the screen.  When the user clicks on a button in the section header the `UITableView` is expanded form the bottom up to cover half of the viewable screen.  The expansion and minimization of the `UITableView` is where the `UITableView` is animated.  When the user clicks the maximize/minimize button the the y component of the `UITableView` frame is changed to move it accordingly.  Here is the code I use to animate the table view:

```
UIImage *downImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowDown.png"];
UIImage *upImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowUp.png"];
UIButton *btnExpandCompress = (UIButton *)sender;
[btnExpandCompress setEnabled:NO];

if (showingTable)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = animatedTable.frame;
        frame.origin.y += animatedTable.frame.size.height - 30;
        animatedTable.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        showingTable = NO;
        [btnExpandCompress setEnabled:YES];
        [btnExpandCompress setBackgroundImage:upImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];
}
else
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = animatedTable.frame;
        frame.origin.y -= animatedTable.frame.size.height - 30;
        animatedTable.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        showingTable = YES;
        [btnExpandCompress setEnabled:YES];
        [btnExpandCompress setBackgroundImage:downImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];
}
```

As can be seen above all I do is change the y component of the frame.  Originally the frame of the `UITableView` has a y component of 583 which is mentioned in the original constraint warning `<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x170a95db0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(538)-[UITableView:0x140330c00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x170199640 )>`.  I don't set any additional constraints for the `UITableView`, just drag it from the object library and move it to its initial minimized position. I am guessing that by changing the frames y component I'm breaking a fixed constraint that is getting set by default.  I hope this additional information helps.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? What constraints do you have on the tableview now? what animation are you attempting?

Comment: What kind of animation you are trying to do? What object will animate? To avoid all the warnings determine the views that might have auto layouts that are affected by your animation then remove them. You can use autolayout and animation if you like.

Comment: I will edit the original post to include more information, I apologize for not providing it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with your tableview 
You have set multiple values for height of tableview
constraint -538 height `tableview`.
As you have set fixed height for tableview

- If you are setting tableview according to navigation bar, means under
  Navigation bar, it should be 504 instead of .
- If you have only one TableView you can remove all the contraints an
  pin that to 0,0,0,0 .

  else you have to show a screenshot of your view controller along with constraints
  Thanks